# Notification for keywords in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

Would it be possible to extend chat to notify when certain **keywords** appear, like [IRC stalkwords](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/IRC/Stalkwords)? That is, when someone writes a keyword they've configured like "unicorn" or "pony", an alert is triggered. This would be shown similar to an @username mention (count over avatar, favicon change, count prefixed to page title).

There are certain topics that I'm interested in learning more about when they come up in a particular room. Also it would be useful in Teacher's Lounge when someone writes "anyone from *XYZ* SE here?" and you happen to be the mod of *XYZ*.

Comment: Are you only looking for specifically stackexchange sites or .. what?

Comment: Like IRC stalk words? This is something we might consider adding to the SE Chat Modification userscript if your request for native support is declined. Feel free to [suggest it](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/issues) if that happens.

Comment: @drachenstern: Yes but it would be probably be handy for more than just that.

Comment: @TimStone: Yes! I didn't know that term until now. Thanks

Comment: @AlexAngas it is always helpful to provide more explicit hints of what you want. So far I figure you just want IDs for specific site names. If you can give more exact details, then it is more likely this can be implemented in some way.

Comment: For public rooms you can grab the RSS

Comment: @TimStone bear in mind that it is most likely going to be necessary to re-enter the list once on each browser, yes?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the breathing-down-the-neck timeliness of having it appear as spoken, you can grab the RSS of a search.

If you're munching for "salads" you'll find the RSS like so:

```
http://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/search/salads
```

Public rooms only though.